# Online Dictionary api not working using retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit, jsonexception

I am trying to make an online dictionary with the use of free dictionary api using retrofit 
I am new in retrofit.Whenever i am running the app ,the app the crashing.

**Logcat Error :**

> com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use
>   JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column
>   1 path $ 07-03 16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1567)
>   07-03 16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1416)
>   07-03 16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:
>   at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:597) 07-03
>   16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:429) 07-03
>   16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:74)
>   07-03 16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
>   07-03 16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:
>   at
>   retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
>   07-03 16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:
>   at
>   retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
>   07-03 16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:
>   at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:116) 07-03
>   16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:     at
>   retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211) 07-03
>   16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:     at
>   retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174) 07-03 16:17:38.531
>   25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:     at
>   retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
>   07-03 16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.mohit.dictionaryapp.DictionaryApi.searchMeaning(DictionaryApi.java:33)
>   07-03 16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.mohit.dictionaryapp.GetMeaningTask.doInBackground(GetMeaningTask.java:27)
>   07-03 16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.mohit.dictionaryapp.GetMeaningTask.doInBackground(GetMeaningTask.java:13)
>   07-03 16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 07-03 16:17:38.531
>   25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 07-03
>   16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 07-03
>   16:17:38.531 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   07-03 16:17:38.532 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   07-03 16:17:38.532 25440-25479/com.mohit.dictionaryapp W/System.err:
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

**DictionaryApi.java**

```
   public class DictionaryApi {

    public interface Alfa{

        @GET("/word.json/{word}/definitions")
        Call<ArrayList<Dictionary>> meaning(@Path("word") String word,@Query("api_key") String api_key);
    }

    public static ArrayList<Dictionary> searchMeaning(String word,String api_key){
        Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://api.wordnik.com/v4/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        Alfa alfa=retrofit.create(Alfa.class);
        Call<ArrayList<Dictionary>> call = alfa.meaning(word,api_key);
        try {
            Response<ArrayList<Dictionary>> response=call.execute();
            Log.e("Dpi", response.message().toString());
            Log.e("Dpi",String.valueOf(response.code()));
            return response.body();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

**Dictionary.java(Pojo)**

```
public class Dictionary {
    public String word;
    public String partOfSpeech;
    public String sequence;
    public String text;
}
```

Dictionary api url:
http://api.wordnik.com/v4/word.json/fantasy/definitions?api_key=a2a73e7b926c924fad7001ca3111acd55af2ffabf50eb4ae5

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Try to remove the "?" in the request. Retrofit manages the query params.

Comment: Nopes,that didnt worked...tried that too...

Comment: Can you show me your retrofit debug log?

Comment: Where can i find it?I think above logcat is retrofit debug log..

Comment: I guess error is because of this line `Call<ArrayList<Dictionary>> call = alfa.meaning(api_key,word);`  this should be like `Call<ArrayList<Dictionary>> call = alfa.meaning(word,api_key);`

Comment: Changed that also...still not working

Comment: Set loglevel to Full in your retrofit configuration. So we can check if the url is correct.

Comment: i had already mentioned url above

Comment: Thank u all it is now working,my mistake was in base url..I have changed my base url from Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://api.wordnik.com/v4/") to Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://api.wordnik.com/") and my end point from  @GET("/word.json/{word}/definitions") to @GET("/v4/word.json/{word}/definitions")

Answer (score 1):

from the JSON response got from your api, try changing the pojo to the one below -

```
public class Dictionary {
    private List<Object> textProns = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private String sourceDictionary;
    private List<Object> exampleUses = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private List<Object> relatedWords = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private List<Object> labels = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private List<Object> citations = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private String word;
    private String partOfSpeech;
    private String attributionText;
    private String sequence;
    private String text;
    private Double score;

    public List<Object> getTextProns() {
    return textProns;
    }

    public void setTextProns(List<Object> textProns) {
    this.textProns = textProns;
    }

    public String getSourceDictionary() {
    return sourceDictionary;
    }

    public void setSourceDictionary(String sourceDictionary) {
    this.sourceDictionary = sourceDictionary;
    }

    public List<Object> getExampleUses() {
    return exampleUses;
    }

    public void setExampleUses(List<Object> exampleUses) {
    this.exampleUses = exampleUses;
    }

    public List<Object> getRelatedWords() {
    return relatedWords;
    }

    public void setRelatedWords(List<Object> relatedWords) {
    this.relatedWords = relatedWords;
    }

    public List<Object> getLabels() {
    return labels;
    }

    public void setLabels(List<Object> labels) {
    this.labels = labels;
    }

    public List<Object> getCitations() {
    return citations;
    }

    public void setCitations(List<Object> citations) {
    this.citations = citations;
    }

    public String getWord() {
    return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
    }

    public String getPartOfSpeech() {
    return partOfSpeech;
    }

    public void setPartOfSpeech(String partOfSpeech) {
    this.partOfSpeech = partOfSpeech;
    }

    public String getAttributionText() {
    return attributionText;
    }

    public void setAttributionText(String attributionText) {
    this.attributionText = attributionText;
    }

    public String getSequence() {
    return sequence;
    }

    public void setSequence(String sequence) {
    this.sequence = sequence;
    }

    public String getText() {
    return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
    }

    public Double getScore() {
    return score;
    }

    public void setScore(Double score) {
    this.score = score;
    }
}
```

Theres a great site called http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ which can help u with the generation of POJO's.

Comment: Alright...I dint see you're solution when posting the answer. My Bad!